# Java Tests stuck at Instantiating tests in Intellij using TestNG

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea, testng

[image]I am facing issues while running tests in intellij. no matter how long i wait, tests are stuck at Instantiating tests. A messgae got displayed "Instantiating tests" and nothing happens.

PS: I am using maven as build tool. I can run the tests from Maven projects which is on right hand side. however when i select directory/single class to run tests it just stuck at "Instantiating tests". Image attached.

Comment: Could you please add more information about your project? Do you use buils tools (Maven , Gradle)? Are there any errors in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...")?

Comment: Also, are there any listeners with before invocations being used that might stall the execution? Does a class with just one TestNG method execute?

Answer (score 2):

actually it was the issue specific to intellij version. i installed 2017.3.4 community edition and working fine.